# Getting light estimation from a single picture using ArCore functions

Tags: arcore

i'm trying to make a program that compute a light estimation (main light direction and intensity and spherical harmonics of the ambient light) of a single picture. I'm trying to use ArCore tools (arcore-android-sdk) to do it but it doesn't work. How can i use ArCore functions (getMainLightIntensity, getMainLightDirections, getSphericalHarmonics) for a single picture ?

Thanks

I've tried to include arcore_c_api.h but the functions code is missing. I've also tried in android studio to write a main function in the hello_ar_application.c but i can't execute it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.